# How to get Class definition in static member variable initialization?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, static-members

I have this code working, but want to improve it:

```
public class VisibleComponent extends Component
{
    static private var itz:Initializer = new Initializer(VisibleComponent);

    // ... omitted
}

public class Initializer
{
    public function Initializer(type:Class)
    {
        Component.registerType(type);
    }
}
```

What I am wondering is:

**Can I automatically get the class object (definition) of `VisibleComponent`?**

**(instead of manually copy-and-paste `VisibleComponent`)?**

For example, something like:

```
public class VisibleComponent extends Component
{
    // not working because `static` member dont have `this`
    static private var itz:Initializer = new Initializer(this.constructor as Class);
}
```

or

```
public class VisibleComponent extends Component
{
    // how to do?
    static private var itz:Initializer = new Initializer(getMyDefinition());
}
```

What I'm trying to do is establishing a `Dictionary` of `string` to `Class` at the very start of program execution, one entry reflects to one class derived extending `Compoenent`.

So with `static` member variable, this initialization would happen at the very start and only once for each classes extending `Component`.

Thanks!

Comment: dont really understand why this question get down-voted :(

Comment: i'm not shore i'd understand correctly you question. Why do you whant this? And how should it work? what profit should privide usig some construction insteed of class name?

Comment: @SentineL I made some edit, please read in my question, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I could understand your question. Why are you using a static private variable?

Comment: @gPeart that variable is to trigger my register process at compile time. static variable initialization would execute before any other codes, so that I can make sure my register process complete first.

Comment: Could someone please tell me why this question get downvoted, please? If I am asking unproper question I can try to improve it, thanks!

Comment: Is that all the code you have in the Initializer class? Why not call Component.registerType somewhere in VisibleComponent? I'm not sure why do you need the Initializer as a static variable.

Comment: Yes that's all at the moment. I want the `registerType` happened only once for each class and at the very start of the program, so I add a static variable to trigger it once and at the very start. Is is way not suitable?

Answer (score 0):

Make the `Initializer` a factory and register the component in there.

```
package {

  public class ComponentFactory {

    private static var _pool:Object = {}; // or make it a final const

    public function create(className:String):Component {
      var clazz:Class = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;
      if (!clazz) {
        throw new Error("Class not found.");
      }
      return register(Component(new class())); // fail fast
    }

    protected function register(c:Component):Component {
      // register the component
      // add dependencies
      // log what you need to log
      return c;
    }

    protected function unregister(c:Component):Component {
      // unregister the component
      // removed dependencies properly
      // log what you need to log
      return c;
    }
  }
}
```

It is easier to implement, to understand and provides proper subclassing ... and you components don't need to know anything about the way, they need to be created. That, is the more important aspect about this.

Comment: Thanks for answering, though I almost give up because there are -2 down-vote. However I can't do it this way. The `className` has to be fully-qualified (with full import path), but in my case I can only make sure the string "VisibleComponent" is correct, the path before it are not fixed. I mean, to add more "Component" is all free for the users in any place, so I made a Dictionary and let user to manually register their Component expansion. Then the real practice is also create Components by string, but the look-up from string to Class is inside my Dictionary.

Comment: Anyway, besides why I've chosen this design, I'd like simply to know is there any method to retrieve the `Class` object without using `this.constructor`? Initially I thought this was a simple question (maybe with just a yes/no), but don't know why everyone is focusing on my design :(